# Posible to export f-curves in blender?

Tags: opengl, blender

I work with some friends on a rail shooter game in openGL. For creating our world we are using Blender. Since we want our Tank to follow a path I have started to work with creating bezier curves and exporting them. That works, but takes a lot of time. Is it possible to export the f-curves you use in the graph editor to an obj-file or any other file that can be used to describe the position for a specific point in time?

I would be grateful if someone has an idea that could be helpful.

Comment: Honestly, this looks much more like a problem for the [Blender forums](http://www.blender.org/forum/) - we aren't Blender specialists (on the whole, anyway), and they might have scripts for this purpose. Personally, I'd go with an alternative format (e.g. 3DS) which supports animation by default (also, 3DS is much more compact).